# Get extended property Microsoft graph javascript api

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-graph-api

I have assigned extended property to my primary calendar and im trying to retrieve that but im not getting it to work.

The docs im following is [graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/multivaluelegacyextendedproperty_get) and [javascript sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript)

```
function postUserCalendar(emailAddress) {
var rand = guid();
const values = {
  MultiValueExtendedProperties: [{
    PropertyId: 'StringArray ' + '{' + rand + '}' + ' Name Palette',
    Value: ["Green", "Aqua", "Blue"]
  }]
};
getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
  if (accessToken) {
    var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) => {
        done(null, accessToken);
      }
    });
    client
      .api('me/calendars/myCalendarId')
      .header('Accept','application/json')
      .patch({
        message: values
      }, (err, res) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
      });
  } else {
    var error = {
      responseText: "Cound not retrieve access token"
    };

  }
 });
}
```

Above is my function to set MultiValueExtendedProperties.
Then i have a function where i try to retrieve those properties.

```
  function getUserCalendar(emailAddress, callback) {
getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
  if (accessToken) {
    // Create a Graph client
    var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) => {
        // Just return the token
        done(null, accessToken);
      }
    });
    client
      .api('/me/calendars/myCalendarId')
      .header('X-AnchorMailbox', emailAddress)
      .expand('multiValueExtendedProperties')
      .filter('id eq {c56fe371-87fb-87a8-1727-9b2b272b9f76}')
      .get((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          callback(null, err);
        } else {
          callback(res.value);
        }
      });
  } else {
    var error = {
      responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token'
    };
    callback(null, error);
  }
 });
}
```

The get request has a status of 200 but i get a jquery error "a is not defined"

If someone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few mistakes in your code that are causing problems.

**Patching the calendar**

Here you pass `{message: values}` as the first parameter to `patch`, which causes incorrect JSON to be passed in the payload. You should just pass values itself, which will serialize correctly:

```
client
    .api('me/calendars/myCalendarId')
    .header('Accept','application/json')
    .patch(values, (err, res) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
     });
```

**Getting the calendar with property expanded**

Here you don't want to use the `filter` method from the SDK. That adds a filter clause to the GET, instead of adding a filter to the `expand`, which is what you want. Instead, embed the filter in the string passed to `expand`, like so:

```
client
    .api('/me/calendars/myCalendarId')
    .header('X-AnchorMailbox', emailAddress)
    .expand("multiValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'StringArray%20{66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00050ec6ac6e}%20Name%20Palette')")
    .get((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(null, err);
        } else {
            callback(res);
        }
    });
```

**Consider using open extensions instead**

We recommend using [open extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension) for storing custom data instead of legacy extended properties. Open extensions are more flexible and easier to work with. Unless there's some compelling reason you need it to be a legacy property (like backwards-compat with an existing solution, etc.), I'd recommend open extensions.

Comment: Thank you for this! I will have a look at open extensions!

Comment: I have an issue, calling `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties` doesn't return the multiValueExtendedProperties response. And if I try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/AAMkADQ0MTkyMDM1LTRhYWQtNGU5NC1iMTNiLWQwMGVkOTc3Njg0YgBGAAAAAADqewFH7jyUQLayRkU-YSm8BwCiRV4wB9ZcTLOUnr6Oobk4AAAAAAEGAACiRV4wB9ZcTLOUnr6Oobk4AAO9PFapAAA=?$expand=multiValueExtendedProperties` same thing, no multiValueExtendedProperties. How to get this property ??